# Which variables to drop in factor analysis

Tags: r, factor-analysis

I have created a factor analysis but confused which variables to take or drop.

I tried taking 12 factors

```
FA_SORT<-fa.sort(FA)                  ## SORTING THE LOADINGS
ls(FA_SORT)   
### LISTING OUT THE OBJECTS
FA_SORT$loadings
#FA_SORT$e.values                                  
Loadings<-data.frame(FA_SORT$loadings[1:ncol(ds),])
```

[image]

Comment: @Gregor How are you.could you please give some thoughts on this

Comment: I don't know a lot about factor analysis. *Probably* this belongs on stats.stackexchange, because it's a question about what to do statistically, rather than how to do it programmatically.

Comment: Yeah. Right. Thanx man.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, looking back to the covariance matrix is often the best place to start investigating dropping/adding variables.

However, I am not sure if there is enough information to give you a straight forward response.
To provide more help answers to the following questions would be helpful:
What package are you using? What does the model look like?  Is there cross loadings?
Do you have apriori hypotheses or this exploratory?  If you have specific hypotheses I would try and make some justfications based on your domain expertise as to why items should or shouldnt be included.

If it is exploratory - have you run an EFA?

IF you are using Lavaan and simply want a data driven response you can use the modindices function.